# SQUASH TA: The rows from two datasests might not be matched properly

Tags: dataset, automated-tests, dbunit

There's what i have done so far:

**test.ta**

```
// -- 1 --
SETUP :
// -- 2 --
LOAD PRE/query1.sql AS query1.file
CONVERT query1.file TO query.sql AS query
// -- 3 --
# LOAD PRE/query1_expected.xml TO XML DATASET expected.dataset

// -- 4 --
TEST :
// -- 5 --
EXECUTE execute WITH query ON DB_INT3_PARC AS raw_result
// -- 6 --
CONVERT raw_result TO dataset.dbunit AS actual.dataset 
// -- 7 --
ASSERT actual.dataset IS equal WITH expected.dataset
```

**query1.sql**

```
SELECT pid.ID ,pid.type , pid.system, P.ID_PRODUIT , p.ref_produit , p.libelle,P.TYPE as P_TYPE,r.id_ressource, p.id_party, p.statut 
FROM parc_produit p, parc_ressource r, parc_produit_id pid
WHERE r.VALEUR = 8933200000000221265 and r.nom_ressource = 'ICCID' AND r.id_produit = p.id_produit 
AND pid.id_produit = p.id_produit AND pid.system = '123'
```

**query1_expected.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<dataset> 
    <default ID="0000009794" TYPE="PFI" SYSTEM="123" ID_PRODUIT="794" REF_PRODUIT='null' LIBELLE='null' P_TYPE="17" ID_RESSOURCE="121" ID_PARTY="101" STATUT="27"/> 
</dataset>
```

When executing ***query1.sql in DB***, the output is :

```
0000009794  PFI 123 794 (null) (null) 17    121 101 27
```

**Assert failed :**

> [FAIL] ASSERT actual.dataset IS equal WITH expected.dataset 
>   org.squashtest.ta.framework.exception.BinaryAssertionFailedException:
>   The actual dataset was different from the expected one

**Execution report:**

> - Table "default": Warning: As table "default" has no (pseudo) primary key, the rows from the two datasets might not be matched properly.
>     {libelle:expected='null'|actual='null'}{ref_produit:expected='null'|actual='null'}

Thanks for any advice..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a ReplacementDataSet [0] in use for the "null"s in the expected dataset?  If not, it is treated as a String.  A String "null" does not equal a null in the actual dataset.

[0] http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/components.html#replacementdataset